# How to add custom tooltip for a listbox items

Tags: xaml, listbox, uwp

I have an Hamburger menu with ListBox ,(Image and Title of the menu item), i bind the list of these data(image and title) to the ListBox, Upto its fine, I want to show a tooltip with the item Title text(on mouse hover on image) with a Teal Background

Comment: Have you solved your question by AVK Naidu's solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show Tooltip on your ListViewItem, Add `ToolTipService` Like Below.

```
<ListViewItem Content="Hello" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom" >
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Teal" />
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="White" Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip> 
</ListViewItem>
```

If you want to do it in `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate >
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="Teal" />
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="White" Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now you can notice that Tool Tip will show you the text with Teal Background. Problem is you still have a faded white border around your Teal Background.

To Correct this, Add [below](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt299160.aspx) to your `Application.Resources` in `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToolTip -->
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToolTipBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ToolTipContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                     MaxWidth="320"
                     Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                     ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                     Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you notice i changed `Padding` to `0`.